# Pageable is not working with @Query in Springboot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Below service is throwing a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` and message is `Index: 0, Size: 0`

It is happening when I am implementing `Pageable` on my method.

What is wrong with this?

**Code base**

```
    public interface TrainingCatalogViewRepository extends JpaRepository<TrainingCatalogView, Integer>
    {
        @Query("SELECT t.catalogId,t.titleShort,t.titleEng from TrainingCatalogView t WHERE LOWER(t.titleEng) LIKE %:titleEng%")            
        Page<GlobalSearchResult> getDataByKeyword(@Param("titleEng") String titleEng, Pageable pageable);

        //I am writing this to select only a few columns. I don't want all properties fo my Entity TrainingCatalogView
        public interface GlobalSearchResult {
            Integer catalogId();
            String titleShort();
            String titleEng();
        }
    }
```

**Update**

Stack Trace

```
[ERROR] 2018-12-27 15:49:01,953 http-nio-8080-exec-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - {} - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0] with root cause
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ProjectingConverter.toMap(ResultProcessor.java:310) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ProjectingConverter.getProjectionTarget(ResultProcessor.java:298) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ProjectingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter$1.convert(ResultProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.domain.Chunk.getConvertedContent(Chunk.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.map(PageImpl.java:104) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.map(PageImpl.java:28) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.processResult(ResultProcessor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:118) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:494) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.getDataByKeyword(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at com.target.learnattargetsearch.controllers.SearchController.globalSearch(SearchController.java:51) ~[main/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.16.RELEASE.jar:1.5.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at com.target.platform.connector.spring.metrics.MetricsRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsRequestFilter.java:37) ~[platform-connector-spring-boot-1.1.4.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.16.RELEASE.jar:1.5.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.16.RELEASE.jar:1.5.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: Provide more code.

Comment: Post whole stack trace.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces: *

The easiest way to limit the result of the queries to only the name attributes is by declaring an interface that exposes **accessor** methods for the **properties** to be read, as shown in the following example: [...] getFirstname() [...] getLastname()*

Comment: I suppose to write interface as `public interface GlobalSearchResult {
            Integer getCatalogId();
            String getTitleShort();
            String getTitleEng();
        }`